# How to display data into Admin panel which is generated by plugin function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am developing a new Plugin and I get the database value into our plugin

function But How to pass these data to view file.I Used following code into the

plugin main file.

```
 <?php
        /*
            Plugin Name: All Attendees
            Plugin URI: http://my-awesomeness-emporium.com
            Description: a plugin to create awesomeness and spread joy
            Version: 1.2
            Author: Mr. Awesome
            Author URI: http://mrtotallyawesome.com
            License: GPL2
        */
    ?>



<?php 

    add_action('init', 'my_register_styles');
    function my_register_styles() {
        add_action('admin_menu', 'all_attendees');
    }
    function all_attendees(){

        $wpdb = EventPlus::getRegistry()->db->getDb();
        $sql = "SELECT id,reg_type,quantity,event_id,lname,fname,payment,payment_status,email FROM wp_evr_attendee ORDER BY id DESC Limit 30";
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        echo "<pre>";print_r($rows);die;
    }

?>
```

Comment: there are different way you can display output of DB to front end, like, shortcode, hook. i suggest you to use shorcode and use if at front end for display data / HTML as well.

Comment: @AshPatel how to get the $row into view file and where I have to create the view file please help about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way to display plugin data, 
One way is use [short code API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

example:

```
 function call_back_function(){
   //function in plugin file with return value,
   //  custom fetch query 
}

add_shortcode('shotcode', 'call_back_function');


echo do_shortcode('[shotcode]'); //for display
```

You can display data in tabular format same as word press post / page tradition as well.

[WP list table for word press admin](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/)

Comment: #Ash patel I want to display data into admin panel

Comment: can you update your question where you want to display data and which type you want to display data?

Comment: #Ash patel I want to display data into table

Comment: check  link for how to display data in word press admin section in my updated answer.You can create admin menu page and apply list table functionality in it.

Comment: @Thanks this link is very useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want display and create template page in dashboard, in that admin template files(main-menu.php,sub-menu.php) you can write whatever you want.**

Go through the below code and paste it in your plugin main file.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'menu_page_name');

function menu_page_name() 
{
    // Add the top-level admin menu


    $page_title = 'title';
    $menu_title = 'title';
    $capability = 'manage_options';
    $menu_slug = 'slug_name';
    $function = 'callback_main_menu';

    add_menu_page($page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);

    // Add submenu page with same slug as parent to ensure no duplicates

     add_submenu_page($menu_slug, 'Plugin Name', 'Plugin Name', $capability, 'pluginname', 'callback_sub_menu');

}

function callback_main_menu() 
{
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) 
    {
    wp_die('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.');
    }
    else
    {
//include your admin template here
    include('templates/main-menu.php');   
    }

    // Render the HTML for the Help page or include a file that does
}
function callback_sub_menu() 
{
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) 
    {
    wp_die('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.');
    }
    else
    {
//include your admin template here
    include('templates/sub-menu.php');   
    }

    // Render the HTML for the Help page or include a file that does
}
```

**If you want to display data or etc on frontend, go through the below code**

```
function plugin_short_code(){
//Return your functionality here
retrn $result;

    }

add_shortcode('plugin_shortcode', 'plugin_short_code');
```

You can use this shortcode in your frontend